# String artifacts from history on commandline

Tags: bash, colors, history

When I scroll through the bash history with the arrow keys and hit (for example) the following string:

```
git clone hgit clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
```

In the next line of history I get something like this:

```
git clone hls
```

Where **ls** is the command from history and **git clone h** is my unwanted artifact.

The following lines from .bashrc are suspect:

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2
YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
ORANGE="\033[38;5;208m"
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0; ${USER}@${HOST}\007"'
PS1="${YELLOW}\u@\h:${ORANGE}\w ${GREEN}\$ "
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ORANGE` is misformed. Instead of this:

```
ORANGE="\033[38;5;208m"
```

It should be, as shown below, just like the others:

```
ORANGE="\[\033[38;5;208m\]"
```